How to create linux-modules-nvidia-555-<kernel version>?
I recently tried to install cuda drivers directly from the Nvidia apt repo.
But the problem I have is my working 535 drivers were overwritten with 555 drivers that seem to be required for the 12.2 cuda libs to work.
The problem is that on reboot Nvida drivers were not found for X, because a matching linux-modules-nvidia-555-{kernel-version} package is not available.
So I removed all of the 555 packages and restore back to the latest 535 nvida package from jammy and jammy-updates.
Is there any work being done to create the linux-modules-nvidia-555-{kernel-version} packages?
Is it possible for me to compile my own linux-modules-nvidia-555-{kernel-version} package?

Hmmm... It is strange that linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-1023-oem actuall only contains some flat files. But I have found that without this module, the Nivia kernel modules won't load.

apt-file list linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-1023-oem

linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-1023-oem: /usr/share/doc/linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-1023-oem/changelog.Debian.gz
linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-1023-oem: /usr/share/doc/linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-1023-oem/copyright

Guessing you're on Ubuntu 22.04 from the 6.5.0 in the package names, so the 545 is the latest Nvidia driver from the standard repos.  The graphics-drivers briefly had the 550 driver, which runs, but got pulled for some reason. nvidia-smi indicates the 545.29.06 driver supports CUDA 12.3. Ubuntu 24.04 has the 545, 550 and 555 nvidia packages but wont install them via the ubuntu-drivers or Software&Updates. Do join launchpad bug 2037004 to turn up the heat on this. Something is in flux, but I'm not sure it's the drivers that are the problem.

linux-modules-nvidia, seems to execute some hidden script to place nvidia kernel modules into /lib/modules/6.5.0-1023-oem. Why does it have to be so obfuscated?

Thanks for the response @ubfan1. I'll help turn up the heat.

I was able to get nvidia 555 with cuda 12.5 running on Ubuntu 24.04....
I had 535 installed and working and I started with the deb(local) install instructions. apt upgrade ran into dependency errors. But after getting through them, I was able to upgrade to 555 with kernel modules installed appropriately.

@ubfan1 24.04 doesn't have 555 driver ready yet. Latest driver available is 550, but default (Avialable through Additional Drivers or ubuntu-drivers) is 535. IIRC the reason is that newer drivers can cause issues with older cards.

555 was from graphics-drivers ppa for 24.04,but sometimes they get removed. Running it now without issues on 3080.
